# How to access a SharePoint 2010 List from a SharePoint 2013 farm

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

We have a SharePoint 2010 farm and a SharePoint 2013 farm.

In one of the List on the SharePoint 2013 farm, when ever a record is created,
we need to copy it to a list on SharePoint 2010 farm.

Can this be done using the 2013 CSOM? Will the 2013 CSOM be able to connect to 2010 List and manipulate it (CRUD operations)
OR
Should I consider creating a Custom Service Application and expose the data stored in 2013 farm for the 2010 farm to consume it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if client object model from 2013 dll will work on SP2010, but you should definitely be able to save an item using listdata.svc REST calls, and then you shouldn't need any custom service application.

Answer (score 0):

We've done from 2007-->2010 (console app) using scom for 2010. The same code run smoothly when we upgraded 2010->2013. So, I guess you won't have any problems.